# Perl script is not sending email

Tags: perl, smtp, mime

I am trying to send my first email (from a windows machine) with Perl, but I am getting an error:

```
SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: at emailer2.pl line 18 (msg->send;)
```

I am totally new to Perl so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?  I have searched for the error but I had no luck finding my exact problem.

Thanks so much for your help!

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$cc = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $message
                 );

$msg->send;
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you don't have a mail server running on your machine. You need to install one and make sure it is running.

Comment: Awesome, that's probably it. Any recommendations what a good one would be?

Comment: That's a really broad (and highly debatable) topic. If you're just trying to test things out on a local machine, however (not for deployment purposes), you might look into [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/). It's not a real server, just an app that shows you what would have been sent from your machine. If you want a real server that can actually deliver mail, I'd recommend asking at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: P.S. Please remember to accept this answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: @Eman 1) Do you have access to SMTP server **on local wired network**? [MIME::Lite support SMTP AUTH but not STARTTLS] 2) Can you install (simplified) Win equivalents of "sendmail"?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use another mail server setting default parameters before sending the message

```
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', "smpt.example.org", Timeout=>60, SSL=>1,
                 AuthUser=>"myself", AuthPass=>"mysecret");
```

Take a look at [MIME::Lite sending section](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#Sending).